# Are preprocessor directives safe for sensitive information?

Tags: c++, security, software-design

I am creating an archive which contains HTML/CSS/JS files for my C++ application, and I don't want users to have access to these files. So, i decided to encrypt archive with password.

My first thought was to store a password inside a program via preprocessor macro (through CMake). But, is it safe?

Can you access the password back from compiled application? (exe, in my case)
And if you can, how to protect from it? Is it technically possible or i should give up and leave it as is?

Comment: If you want to prevent users from accessing those files, then those files need to belong to a separate user (e.g. a user account that is associated with the application, preferably one that has logins disabled).    Then the application that accesses the files needs to be installed in a manner specific to the operating system so the program can access the files but the user running the program cannot (e.g. a `setuid` program under modern flavours of unix).  In other words, the operating systems security model need to be exploited to ensure only the program can access the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the macro is actually used in the application then yes, it's accessible in the executable file -- it *has* to be for the program to use it.

Any credential you embed in your program can be recovered by a sufficiently-motivated attacker.  There is no encryption mechanism you can use to prevent this, as you would need to provide the decryption key for the program to function.

The proof is very simple: if the program itself can obtain the credential without any user input, then the executable file must contain the key, or all of the information needed to produce/derive the key.  Therefore, it *must* be possible for *anyone* (with the requisite expertise) to produce the credential with only the information in the executable file.

This could be done by inspecting the executable.  It could also be done by running the executable under the supervision of a debugger and watching what it is doing.

This is the same reason [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) schemes are pointless -- the consumer must be in possession of a key to use the material, and if they can get their hands on the key (they must be able to in order for them to consume the content) then they scheme doesn't work.  (Of course, in newer DRM schemes the key is buried in a chip that is designed to destroy the key if it is opened, but that just means it's *difficult* to get the key, not impossible.)

---

tl;dr: It's never a question of whether it's possible to recover an embedded key.  It's always possible.  It's a question of *how much effort it will take* to recover that key.